# Export Blender Shape-keys to Xcode

Tags: animation, export, shape-keys, dae

How can I export my Blender shape-keys to Xcode? I have one shape-key that I would like to export and I am somewhat new to Blender. Xcode uses an .SCN format and I don't know how to get the shape-keys from Blender into that. When I tried enabling shape-keys in export options and exporting to Collada (.dae), the shape keys did not appear in Xcode. The shape key doesn't have any animations, it is just saved as a shape-key.
[image: This is what I see in Xcode.]

[image: This is the Shape key I have for my mesh in Blender. There are no animations at all.]